# How does Jumper work with Warp in terms of carrying people with you?

Tags: teleportation, gurps-4e, gurps

Someone with the Jumper (world-jumper) advantage can escort other people with the Jumper (world-jumper) advanatge, according to b. 64. You can also take warp and the warp jump enhancement, to be able to teleport on the world you are visiting. Would this allow you to bring along other people on your warps when you are Warp Jumping? Would you be able to bring Jumpers along on Warps that remain on the same world?

Comment: I've set a reminder for myself to check the wording on this when I'm home with access to my books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will make it clear:

B64, near top of center column, "However, if multiple Jumpers *of the same kind* are in physical contact, when one jumps, the others can "hitch a ride" if they wish -- even if the Jumper who initiates the jump does *not* want company." (italics in original)

To me, at least, this is clear on two points: the Jumpers who "hitch a ride" must be the same kind of Jumper -- whether this is timejumper, worldjumper, or omni-jump -- and I would interpret this to mean that if the initiating Jumper has Warp, the others must as well -- not just to follow on a jump that uses Warp, but to follow that jumper on *any* jump.

Of course, your Warp Jumper could *carry* one other along on any jump they can make themselves, if they have Extra Carrying Capacity sufficient to the additional weight.

All of this is per B64, Jumper section.

Warp, B97-98, lacks the "hitchhiker" feature (that is, others with Warp cannot follow along without having some means to *know*, well enough to Warp there, where the Warper went); the only to take someone else along on a Warp within the same world or time is if they have Extra Carrying Capacity sufficient for the weight involved.

Answer (score -3):

If you had warp-world-jump, you would **not** be able to carry other people without world-jumping or adding Extra Carrying Capacity to Warp as jumping benefits should only affect people who are currently jumping. However, if you had warp-time-jump, you would always be able to carry time-jumpers on your Warp as we are all traveling in time all the time.